# Should I be worried about the current PubNub configuration when I upgrading to FCM?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, pubnub, firebase-cloud-messaging

While reading through GCM documentation, I found the alert message from the site:

> Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) is the new version of GCM. It inherits
>   the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure, plus new features! See
>   the FAQ to learn more. If you are integrating messaging in a new app,
>   start with FCM. GCM users are strongly recommended to upgrade to FCM,
>   in order to benefit from new FCM features today and in the future.

How does it affect to current running PubNub configuration when I upgrading to FCM? I'm still not sure if ugprading from GCM to FCM will be just a snap.

[Upgrade to GCM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZ8xN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PubNub Mobile Push Gateway - GCM to FCM

FCM is mostly just a rebranding of GCM (GCM used to be called C2DM and this is similar transition). It appears the changes are primarily client side (easier to user SDKs). PubNub (and other GCM push providers) [do not have to make any changes on the server side at this time](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq).

As always, PubNub will continue to monitor updates to push notifications services like GCM and APNS and provide new features as needed.

Please contact [PubNub Support](http://pubnub.com/support) if you have any issues using GCM/FCM with your PubNub enabled applications.

For more details about using GCM/APNS with PubNub, see these resources:

- [Sending APNS and GCM Messages to Subscribers and Mobile Push Notification Services in One API Call](https://www.pubnub.com/community/discussion/498/sending-apns-and-gcm-messages-to-subscribers-and-mobile-push-notification-services-in-one-api-call)
- [Android V4 Mobile Push Gateway Tutorial](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/android/mobile-gateway-sdk-v4)
- [Mobile Push Notification Gateways, APNS, GCM, and Data Streams Explained (video)](https://vimeo.com/116921132)
- [How can I troubleshoot my push notification issues?](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/1127/how-can-i-troubleshoot-my-push-notification-issues)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there will be any issue moving your client from GCM to FCM. A client that implements FCM can receive messages sent to GCM, it is the same infrastructure. If PubNub is sending messages through GCM then your FCM client be able to handle those messages.

Note that GCM is still being supported. So if you are concerned about PubNub's implementation then sticking with GCM is a valid option.